# Reorder options inside select depending on the URL

Tags: php

Here is the function that grabs the locations and pops them into a select list.

```
function get_hourly_locations_list($class ='', $name = '', $option = 'Select Option') {
    $terms = get_terms( 'location', 'orderby=ID&hide_empty=0' );
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        echo '<select class="' . $class . ' req" id="' . $name . '" name="' . $name . '" style="width:100%;">';
        echo '<option value="0">' . $option . '</option>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

            if (get_term_meta($term->term_id,'fcb_can_hourly',true) == 'on') {

                echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';

            }

        }
        echo '</select>';
    }

}
```

Each hourly type has their own value for example. etc

```
<option value="3">bangkok hotels and areas</option>
<option value="65">Pattaya hotels and areas</option>
```

I am trying to use something on the lines of `<?php if (is_page(478)) { would be a pattaya page... }` then show only the value of 65 (being the pattaya option) or put value 65 as the first choice inside the select.

EDIT.

I decided to get those specific destination values by querying them from the DB, this allowed to only grab the IDs that were only needed in this case.

```
function get_locations_list_pattaya_start($class ='', $name = '', $option = 'Select Option',$extra=null) {
    global  $wpdb;
    $bookings = $wpdb->get_results("select term_id, name from wp_terms");
    echo '<select '.$extra.' class="' . $class . ' req" id="' . $name . '" name="' . $name . '" style="width:100%;">';
        echo '<option value="' . $bookings[1]->term_id . '">' . $bookings[1]->name . '</option>';
        echo '<option value="' . $bookings[64]->term_id . '">' . $bookings[64]->name . '</option>';
        echo '<option value="' . $bookings[2]->term_id . '">' . $bookings[2]->name . '</option>';
        echo '<option value="' . $bookings[3]->term_id . '">' . $bookings[3]->name . '</option>';
        echo '<option value="' . $bookings[71]->term_id . '">' . $bookings[71]->name . '</option>';
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: What are `get_terms()` and `get_term_meta()` look like, I think those functions need to be included by you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it selected you can do this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$term->term_id.'"'.(is_page($term->term_id) ? ' selected' : '').'>'.$term->name.'</option>';
```

so that the if the value matches, it is selected by default

Comment: this looks promising

Comment: Since i dont have no pages that are titled /65 or /3 etc how would work?

Comment: It looks like is_page tests the current page by an integer value and returns a boolean. The definition for that function is not provided